# Probability both hits are crits

Tags: probability

A friend of mine recently asked me this question and we couldn't agree on a solution.

"You hit an enemy twice. At least one of the hits is a crit. Assuming a 50% crit chance, what is the probability both hits are crits?"

How to solve it?

Comment: What were your solutions, and what was the main point of contention?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the number of crits.

$$P(X = 2 \mid X \ge 1) = \frac{P(X=2, X \ge 1)}{P(X \ge 1)} = \frac{P(X=2)}{1 - P(X =0)} = \frac{0.5^2}{1 - 0.5^2} = \frac{1}{3}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The a priori options for the two hist (in order) are $cc'$, $c'c$, $cc$, $c'c'$ where $c$ stands for "crit", and $c'$ for a "non-crit". All 4 are equally likely. But you're given that at least one is a crit, so $c'c'$ cannot have happened. Now $cc$ is one of the three (still equally likely) options, so the answer is $\frac13$.